# how to download a pdf file in phantom

Tags: java, phantomjs

This code is to download the pdf file in phantom but it is not downloading,can any one help me out in this...

And i need to give downloadfilepath for the download file.

```
package core;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;  

public class Phantom {              
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


                    Capabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
                    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);                
                    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", true); 
                    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, 
                            new String[] {"--ssl-protocol=tlsv1"});

                    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path","..../phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs");


                    String[] phantomArgs = new  String[] {
                            "--webdriver-loglevel=NONE"
                    };
                    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, phantomArgs);

                    WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
                   //Sample site to download the pdf file
                    driver.get("https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265262543_HTML_Web_Design_in_7_days");

                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
                    System.out.println("Page url is: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());

                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='blue-link js-download btn btn-large btn-promote']")).click(); //Click on the link to download

                    // After the above click, file should download but it doesn't not happens 
                    driver.quit();          
           }        
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Can you try this url inside get method, https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Siamak_Sarmady/publication/265262543_HTML_Web_Design_in_7_days/links/55b89d4908aed621de05eff4/HTML-Web-Design-in-7-days.pdf?origin=publication_detail

Comment: No error  after running the code

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Siamak_Sarmady/publication/265262543_HTML_Web_Design_in_7_days/links/55b89d4908aed621de05eff4/HTML-Web-Design-in-7-days.pdf?origin=publication_detail, try from this link inside get method

Comment: I tried the url u gave but still the download is not happening..